# Opening another page in HTML

Tags: html, hyperlink

In my website, I have an html file inside of a folder, that is next to the index file. I want to add a link back to the index file.

For example, the URL for the index would be, example.com. The 2nd page is example.com/pages/example.html. How would i send the user back to the index page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the following structure:

```
website.com/index.html
website.com/pages/example.html
```

You have three options -- two relative links, and one absolute link:

Relative to `example.html`:

```
<a href="../index.html">Back to the index</a>
```

Relative to the root (note the slash):

```
<a href="/index.html">Back to the index</a>
```

Absolute:

```
<a href="http://example.com/index.html">Back to the index</a>
```

I'd recommend using a relative root, as your website URL may change in the future, so you don't really want to hardcode it.

As for which of the two relative approaches to use, **relative to the root** (`/index.html`) would be best in your base, as it will *always* take you back to the index -- you may move `example.html` to the same folder as index, or even a subfolder of `pages`, in which case the second relative link would need modification. If you have that link in multiple pages, that could prove annoying ;)

For further reading on relative and absolute URLs, I recommend checking out the [Coffee Cup article](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_EvfJKNs-5ZQVZHYThDZkRTQ00/view This is what happens, because the index file is not in the same location as the file that needs to access the index file.

Comment: Is `index.html` in the same folder as `example.html`? Note that this is a [relative link](http://www.extropia.com/tutorials/web_design/relative_absolute_links.html), so they must both be in the same folder for this example to work.

Comment: No, the whole point of my post was because i needed to go back to the index file without needing the index and the example.html file in the same folder. This is my folder structure.

Code
    -index.html
    -pages(folder)
        -example.html

I need to open index while within example.html.

Comment: Yes; my apologies -- I slightly misunderstood your question. I've updated my answer to cover this :)

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Sorry if I sounded a bit rude. I didn't mean to if i did.

Comment: You didn't sound rude at all! -- I was too quick, and slightly misread the question. Hopefully my edit to my answer will give you a clear understanding of the various approaches :)

Comment: Also, if this answer solved the problem for you, please don't forget to mark the solution as correct -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things flowing smoothly :)