# How to create new folders on my domain name

Tags: file-upload

As you can tell from the title, I don't know what words that I should use to describe what I want to do.

I just want to be able to change my website's files from:

`www.example.com/bark.php`

and `www.example.com/leaves.php`

to

`www.example.com/tree/bark.php`

`www.example.com/tree/leaves.php`

While having a `www.example/tree.php` page as well.

So, I'm working with PHP and am building this with Sublime text editor. Is this an `.htaccess` job?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You don't need `.htaccess` or **any** language. Simply create the folder, put your files in it, and remember to upload them back to the server. You'll also want to delete the old files on the server as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `.htaccess` or any programming language.

Simply create the folder, put your files in it, and upload them back to the server. You'll also want to delete the old files on the server as well.

Alternatively, you can rename the files on the server itself. You can either right-click on the target file, and click 'Move'.

You can also drag the files directly by clicking-and-dragging:

[image: cPanel]

The file `www.example.com/tree.php` is just another file, stored in the **ROOT** folder. You are allowed to have a folder and a file with the same name.

`www.example.com/tree` will point to the tree **folder**, and attempt to access the index at `www.example.com/tree/index.html` or `www.example.com/tree/index.php`.

The file `www.example.com/tree.php` will **not** be loaded when viewing `www.example.com/tree` without `.htaccess` configuration.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you Obsidian Age for your help.

The problem that I'm having now is that how I'm linking to .php files in the root directory.  

For example, I want to "include"

<?php   include "menu.php"; ?>

but since this file is located in the root directory, I'm getting errors. How should I correctly link to this from the newly created folder?

Thanks you :)

Comment: @Adam -- You're looking for a **relative link** (`include "../menu.php"`). That goes 'up' one folder to the immediate parent. Also note that you can access the **root** folder directly by writing *only* the backslash before the filename: `include "/menu.php"`. Either of those will link the file for you. For more information on **relative**, **root-relative**, and **absolute** links, please see [**this earlier answer of mine**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41731393/2341603) :)

Comment: Yes! I now have folders. So excited, thanks for your help Obsidian Age!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear this solution appears to have helped you. Once you've confirmed this solution solves your problem, please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things on StackOverflow flowing smoothly :)